# CloseableHttpClient throws an error: org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute with java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, php, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to use `CloseableHttpClient` from Apache HTTPComponents Client 4.5.9 to upload a file via HTTP request to a PHP script on the server.

While running the program, I am having the following error:

```
Jul 15, 2019 8:26:39 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://homelegacytech.com:80: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
Jul 15, 2019 8:26:39 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://homelegacytech.com:80
```

Here is my Java code:

```
try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build())
{
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://homelegacytech.com/uploads.php");
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user.getUserName()));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    File file = new File(this.zipFileURL);
    MultipartEntityBuilder mpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    ContentType contentType = ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA;
    MyFileBody cbFile = new MyFileBody(file, contentType);
    mpEntity.addPart("zip_file", cbFile);
    httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity.build());
    System.out.println("Sending request to: " + httpPost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if(resEntity != null)
        System.out.println("Response: " + EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    if(resEntity != null)
        EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
}
```

Here is my PHP code on the server:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['zip_file']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['zip_file']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['zip_file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['zip_file']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['zip_file']['name'])));

      if($file_ext !== 'zip'){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a zip file.";
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
```

Please what could be the problem, because the file is not uploading?
Also the file is just around 5MB and it's a zip file.